# any good sourcebook for plane geometry problems?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

I wanted to find some good resource books for **euclidean plane geometry**.
would anybody name some titles?

Comment: Not a book, but [gogeometry](http://gogeometry.com/problem/) has plenty of problems.

Answer (score 1):

*Advanced Euclidean Geometry* (formerly called *Modern Euclidean Geometry*) by Roger A. Johnson

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a compendium of problems, I think that [Problems in Plane and Solid Geometry](http://students.imsa.edu/~tliu/Math/planegeo.pdf) by Prasolov is very hard to beat! It contains hundreds of problems with solutions.